# Dimension and mass of space debris

Tags: debris, reference-request

I am doing a project on space debris management. I wanted to know the size and shape of common space debris (like rocket upper rocket stages). Is there a website which has data on debris? I know websites like https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=25861 contains data regarding the orbit of objects in space. I was wondering if there was something similar for the shape of these objects.

Kind regards,
Rohit

Comment: www.n2yo.com,  www.celestrak.com  etc - use NORAD  public data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set

Answer (score 1):

The best single resource I can think of would be Gunters Space Page, it has an entire section on upper stages. https://space.skyrocket.de/directories/upperstages.htm

This site also has details of a huge number of satellites, many of which are now defunct space debris too.

It depends how much detail you want to get into, this includes length and diameter with pictures of the stages. I'm sure you could find 3D models for many of them if you look into individual rockets.